# How to print a string in literal characters in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to print all the special characters like "\n", "\t", "\r" in the string I get from some file. These characters are originally in the string and don't change the string, since I don't really know what are these special characters.

How?

Comment: Backquote instead of backslash.

Comment: If those are the *literal* characters in the strings, you shouldn't have an issue, as slashes have no special meaning in **PowerShell** strings, both literal and expansion. If you are constructing *regular expressions*, you need to `[Regex]::Escape(<string>)' any string you want to serve as a *literal* match.

Comment: Why? What are you doing?

Comment: @alexzelaya When I read a file into a string. I want to know what are the characters of the new line. "\n" or "\r\n". Or tab or space.

Comment: @dspjm yes, but why? what is the goal?

Comment: `\n` is a newline, `\t` is a tab, `\r` is a carriage return. The combination of `\r\n` is a carriage return and a newline, and is used as the line ending combination on DOS/Windows computers. None of them produce printable characters - they're all for formatting purposes. The ASCII values in hex are `0x0A`, `0x08` and `0x0D` respectively. With that said, you need to be much more clear what you're asking - I can't tell what it is based on what you've written so far, and it seems others can't either.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your problem, not only a description.

Comment: @alexzelaya I wanted to use string replace in powerhsell and find out whether the new line is \r\n or \n. \t or whitespace. AFAIK, there are some conflicts when sharing codes between Linux and Windows, this output may be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your latest comment, do you mean to do something like this where space, tab and newline characters are replaced by some readable so you can tell what that whitespace is?

```
# demo text
$text = @"
Here's some demo text with a Tab:`t, a Carriage Return:`r, a Newline:`n and


several more newlines
"@


# create a Hashtable of the whitespace characters
$charmap = @{
    ' '  = '[SPACE]'
    "`t" = '[TAB]'
    "`r" = '[CR]'
    "`n" = '[LF]'
}

# define a scriptblock to do the actual replacement in the text
$matchEvaluator = {
    param($match)
    $charmap."$match"
}

[regex]::Replace($text, ($charmap.Keys -join '|'), $matchEvaluator)
```

The result of the above will be

```
Here's[SPACE]some[SPACE]demo[SPACE]text[SPACE]with[SPACE]a[SPACE]Tab:[TAB],[SPACE]a[SPACE]Carriage[SPACE]Return:[CR],[SPACE]a[SPACE]Newline:[LF][SPACE]and[CR][LF][CR][LF][CR][LF]several[SPACE]more[SPACE]newlines
```